# Unable to see RestTemplate metrics using micrometer

Tags: spring-micrometer

Unable to see the RestTemplate metrics on springboot 2 micrometer.

```
 @Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().build();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor(API_KEY_HEADER, apiKey));
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler());
    return restTemplate;
}

<dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-signalfx</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

RestTemplate related metrics having stats for 200's, 400's are missing both in signalfx and /actuator/metrics. My understanding is that such metrics are automatically logged and doesn't require coding manual counters.

Answer (score 7):

You need to wire in the RestTemplateBuilder instead of: new RestTemplateBuilder().